# Filter first x number of grouped matches per column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a situation where each column on my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VytH0tYPoUl43FWiDHBu6Mr0gNn3_gSE44w-7CxBVnA/edit#gid=1873646115) represents a different topic, and every column contains 5 groups of 3 rows outlining details on the topic along with an assigned name and status.

[image: example data]

What I've been attempting to solve is how to use a formula on another sheet which searches each column from top to bottom and displays the topic details for the first 3 matches of a specified name if the status is not "Complete".

[image: filtered data]

What would be the recommended way to accomplish this? I have done some [testing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VytH0tYPoUl43FWiDHBu6Mr0gNn3_gSE44w-7CxBVnA/edit#gid=1446327584) with FILTER/INDEX/MATCH but that does not seem to suffice for this level of filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(split(sortn(tocol(if((DATA!$C4:$E16=A7)*(DATA!$C5:$E17<>"Complete"),DATA!$C2:$E2&"|"&DATA!$C3:$E15,),1),3),"|"))
```

[image]

***final formula***:

```
=index(split(array_constrain(tocol(if((DATA!$C4:$E16=A7)*(DATA!$C5:$E17<>"Complete"),DATA!$C2:$E2&"|"&DATA!$C3:$E15,),1,1),3,1),"|"))
```

Comment: This is nearly exactly what I was trying to accomplish, although do you know of a way to have the filtered data appear from top to bottom as it appears on the DATA sheet? Currently it seems to be sorted alphabetically, so if I change the word '3rd' to 'third' in '3rd details for Topic B' for Bob, it appears after '4th details for Topic B' for Bob on the FILTERED sheet.

Comment: removed the `sort` part of the formula now.

Comment: While that seemed to work with Bob's topics, now the order for John and Will are reversed, any ideas why that might be happening?