# Sort output of index based on values not in array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VytH0tYPoUl43FWiDHBu6Mr0gNn3_gSE44w-7CxBVnA/edit?usp=sharing) where each column represents a different topic, and every column contains 5 groups of 5 rows outlining the topic details along with an assigned name and status.

[image]

Thanks to @rockinfreakshow's help on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75857389/filter-first-x-number-of-grouped-matches-per-column) thread, I am using the following formula to search each column from top to bottom and display the topic and its details for the first 5 matches of a specified name if the status is not 'Complete':

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TOCOL(IF(($C5:$I21=B32)*($C6:$I22<>"Complete"),$C2:$I2&"|"&$C3:$I19,),1,1),5,1),"|"))
```

[image]

What I am trying to figure out now, however, is how to sort this data by the priority levels in rows 4, 8, 12, 16, and 20. (If there is no priority level, the data should appear in the order of the columns from top to bottom, left to right, after the data with priority levels.) This is the order in which I want the data to be output:

[image]

I have tried using SORT but I am not sure how to point it toward the priority data, as this seems to be sorting by the data in the first row of the array:

```
=INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TOCOL(IF(($C5:$I21=B32)*($C6:$I22<>"Complete"),$C2:$I2&"|"&$C3:$I19,),1,1),5,1),"|"),3,1))
```

How would I best accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can `sort` once you include the **Priority rows** (`&"|"&$C4:$I20`) as well in the existing formula & in the final step you can exclude this new\extra column using `choosecols()`:*

```js
=choosecols(sortn(split(tocol(if(($C5:$I21=B32)*($C6:$I22<>"Complete"),$C2:$I2&"|"&$C3:$I19&"|"&$C4:$I20,),1,1),"|"),5,,3,1),1,2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Create a custom `filter_` function which gives the desired `res`ult `R`a`ng`e in a single `(TO)COL`umn, `IF` the input `dataRange` is equal to a specific `cond`ition, say `Bob`.
- Use this `filter_` to get the `topics`, `priority`, `details`and `status` by providing the necessary `OFFSET`.
- `FILTER` the `combinedData` based on `status`
- Finish off with a `SORTN` based on `priority`.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
    dataRng, C3:E22,
    cond, B24,
    filter_,LAMBDA(resRng,TOCOL(IF(dataRng=cond,resRng,))),
    topics, filter_(C2:E2),
    priority, filter_(OFFSET(dataRng,-1,0)),
    details, filter_(OFFSET(dataRng, -2,0)),
    status, filter_(OFFSET(dataRng, 1,0)),
    combinedData, FILTER({topics,details, priority},status<>"Complete"),
    SORTN(combinedData,5,2,3,1) 
))
```

| Topics | Details | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TOPIC B | 4th details for Topic B | 1 |
| TOPIC A | Details for Topic A | 2 |
| TOPIC A | More details for Topic A | 3 |
| TOPIC C | 4th details for Topic C | 4 |
| TOPIC B | Third details for Topic B | 5 |